# for loop of c++ initializes wrong iterator

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I tried to write a simple program to check some numbers. It just refuses to work. Below code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void checknumber(int i)
{
if(i>9)
{
    if(i%2==0) {cout<<"even"<<endl;}
    else {cout<< "odd" << endl;}
}
else
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
            cout<<"one"<<endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"two"<<endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"three"<<endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout<<"four"<<endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout<<"five"<<endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout<< "six"<<endl;
            break;
        case 7:
            cout<<"seven"<<endl;
            break;
        case 8:
            cout<<"eight"<<endl;
            break;
        case 9:
            cout<<"nine"<<endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    }
}


int main() {

int a,b;
cin >> a >> b;
for (int i=a; i==b; i++)
{
    checknumber(i);
}

return 0;
}
```

Function works fine. But, main program refuses to work as I expected.

input: 3 10, output: nothing. I debugged it and found that I have to initialize to a very negative number around -27k.

Comment: `for (int i=a; i==b; i++)`, Do you really want the loop to run only when `a==b`?

Comment: `for (int i=a; i==b; i++)` -- Ok.  What C++ book for beginners shows a `for` loop that is written like this?  Either this is your invention, or you need to re-read the chapter on `for` loops and what the middle condition means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop's condition part is not correct. Try:

```
for (int i=a; i<=b; i++)
              ^^^^
```

If I understand the problem correctly you want to run it from 3 to 10.

In your case `for (int i=a; i==b; i++)` condition `i==b` will be checked only once, so loop will break at first condition where (3 == 10) is **false**. In example of 3 to 10 it will break in first condition.

Comment: hi...if it works once, then there should be some output right?

Answer (score 1):

> I debug it and find I to be initialized to a very large negative number instead of 'a'.

It's likely that you didn't debug correctly. In any case, this loop:

```
for (int i=a; i==b; i++)
```

will only execute once if `a == b`, and zero times otherwise. You probably want:

```
for (int i=a; i!=b; i++)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried both answers above. it's still not working. I is initialized to -272631984

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = a; i == b; i++)
{
    checknumber(i);
}
```

You cannot solve this problem like this. Do

```
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        checknumber(i);
    }
```

Then your problem will solve correctly.